# How to extract JSON array fields using HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, httparty

I am using FOOD2FORK api to extract data using HTTParty in ruby.

My code :

```
require 'httparty'  #Note : This file is in the models >> filename.rb
#Don't need to require when using bundler
#Restful Web Services 
#1. Base URI 2. Support XML or JSON 3. Support HTTP operations (GET, POST)
#Think of web at MVC : website you can get resources in any format 
#HTTParty parses XML or JSON for you (like your browser - it's a client).  Parses into a Ruby hash or array

class Recipe
    include HTTParty
    ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"] = "5b6b74c6cc0fa9dc23871a7ae753f6c7"

    base_uri "https://food2fork.com/api" #Same across most requests 
    default_params key: ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"], fields: "image_url" #defaults, like API developer key #fields: "image_url, source_url, title",
    format :json #Tell it which format data comes in
    #q:"search" request parameter 

    def self.for (keyword) 
        #class method called for which takes in a term 
        get("/search", query: {q: keyword})["recipes"]  #get is method provided by HTTParty 


        #returns array where each element in the array is a hash 
    end 
    pp Recipe.for "chocolate"
end
```

It's returning me

```
[
  {
    "publisher"=>"BBC Good Food", 
    "f2f_url"=>"http://food2fork.com/view/9089e3", 
    "title"=>"Cookie Monster cupcakes", 
    "source_url"=>"http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/873655/cookie-monster-cupcakes",
    "recipe_id"=>"9089e3", 
    "image_url"=>"http://static.food2fork.com/604133_mediumd392.jpg", 
    "social_rank"=>100.0, 
    "publisher_url"=>"http://www.bbcgoodfood.com"
  }
]
```

But I only want to extract it's `image_url` even on using `field` it's extracting the whole data set any idea how to extract only image_url ?

> P.S You can check the format of JSON here -
>   http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=65987bf1f4b22007c365c243f5670f35&q=shredded%20chicken

Comment: Assuming,  you are storing the response `response.map{|res| res["image_url"]}` should do the trick for you.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to return only the `image_urls` as response. This I think is not possible since it is an external API. You can fetch the `image_urls` from the response though with this `response[:recipes].map{|x| x['image_url']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work

```
response = your response from API

response_data = JSON.parse(response.body).with_indifferent_access

response_data['recipes'].each do |recipe|
  puts recipe['image_url'] # image_url of block
end
```

Comment: 1. `with_indifferent_access` makes no sense; 2. this code produces several local variables inside a block, immediately discarded and returns nothing useful. The comment by @KedarnagMukanahallipatna above is correct and should be considered the valid answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa 1) it make sense if developer want to fetch with symbol instead of string 2) Yes. i know it will produce lots local variables and its not useful but its only for understanding of OP